# Pygame coordinates sync between different objects

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am using pygame to make a simple 2d game.
I am trying to make player shoot bullets using his gun.
However, for some reason bullets always follow player and sync their positions with him.

```
from pygame.locals import *
from threading import Thread
import time


class GameObject:
    """Base object class"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Init all base values"""
        self.hp = 100
        self.coordinates = [0, 0]
        self.speed = 3

    def move_x(self, where):
        """Moving player by x axis"""
        self.coordinates[0] += where * self.speed

    def move_y(self, where):
        """Moving player by y axis"""
        self.coordinates[1] += where * self.speed


class Gun(GameObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.coordinates = [25, 25]
        self.bullets = []
        self.direction = [1, 1]

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, (28, 28, 28),
                         pygame.Rect(self.coordinates[0], self.coordinates[1], 40, 10))

    def shoot(self):
        self.bullets.append(Bullet())
        self.bullets[-1].shoot(self.coordinates)


class Bullet(GameObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.direction = [1, 0]

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, (255, 0, 43),
                         pygame.Rect(self.coordinates[0], self.coordinates[1], 40, 10))

    def shoot(self, start_pos):
        print("shooting!!!")
        self.coordinates = start_pos
        shoot_thread = Thread(target=self.shoot_thread)
        shoot_thread.start()

    def shoot_thread(self):

        for i in range(15):
            print("MOVING")
            self.move_x(self.direction[0] * self.speed)
            self.move_y(self.direction[1] * self.speed)
            self.draw()
            time.sleep(0.1)


class Player(GameObject):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initiating all base values"""
        super().__init__()
        self.direction = "UP"
        self.gun = Gun()

    def check_move(self):
        if pygame.key.get_mods() == 1:
            self.speed = 5
        else:
            self.speed = 3
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_e]:
            self.gun.shoot()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_a]:
            self.move_x(-1)
            self.gun.move_x(-1)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_d]:
            self.move_x(1)
            self.gun.move_x(1)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
            self.move_y(-1)
            self.gun.move_y(-1)
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
            self.move_y(1)
            self.gun.move_y(1)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, (255, 0, 0),
                         pygame.Rect(self.coordinates[0], self.coordinates[1], 50, 50))
        self.gun.draw()


# class Bullet(GameObject):


pygame.init()

# Colours
BACKGROUND = (255, 255, 255)

# Game Setup
FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1080
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('super_shooter228')


# The main function that controls the game
def main():
    """Main function that does all the render"""
    looping = True
    # Get input

    player = Player()  # Init of the player structure
    while looping:
        pygame.event.get()
        player.check_move()  # Moving the player
        WINDOW.fill(BACKGROUND)  # This fills the backgroud with whatever you want, do all rendering after this!!
        player.draw()

        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS


main()
```

I did my best to find the solution on the internet but I failed.
I would really appreciate any help with this question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely coming from the way that the `shoot` methods share data:

```
# Gun
    def shoot(self):
        self.bullets.append(Bullet())
        self.bullets[-1].shoot(self.coordinates)

# Bullet
    def shoot(self, start_pos):
        print("shooting!!!")
        self.coordinates = start_pos
```

`coordinates` is a list, which is a mutable container -- a list can be modified at any time after you've passed it to another function.  When your `Gun` passes its coordinates to `Bullet`, both objects end up sharing the same list -- so when the gun moves (which happens whenever the player moves), all of the bullets move -- and by the same token, when the bullets move, the gun moves too!

The way I'd suggest preventing this type of bug would be to store your `coordinates` as a tuple rather than a list:

```
class GameObject:
    """Base object class"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Init all base values"""
        self.hp = 100
        self.coordinates = (0, 0)
        self.speed = 3

    def move_x(self, where):
        """Moving player by x axis"""
        x, y = self.coordinates
        self.coordinates = x + where * self.speed, y

    def move_y(self, where):
        """Moving player by y axis"""
        x, y = self.coordinates
        self.coordinates = x, y + where * self.speed
```

Tuples are immutable, which means:

- you can't modify individual elements of them.  Therefore...
- you can only modify them by creating a whole new tuple.  Therefore...
- anything else you shared a tuple with will still have the original version of it

For tracking pieces of independent game state, this is a good thing because it keeps a change to one object's state from unintentionally affecting another object.

The *other* option would be to continue using a list but to be very careful that you copy the list whenever you pass it around, e.g.:

```
# Gun
    def shoot(self):
        self.bullets.append(Bullet())
        self.bullets[-1].shoot(self.coordinates.copy())
```

This is a slightly easier fix to this particular bug -- but with this fix, it's also going to be very easy for a similar bug to pop up in the future, which is why I recommend the route of using a tuple instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never knew that python uses links instead of copies. I appreciate your help.